# total_pages return in pagination with rails and kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

i want a pagination in my page, im using ruby and kaminari to this.

```html
class ServicesController < ApplicationController
 def index
  /@services = Service.order(name: :asc)/
  @organs = Admin::Organ.all
 
  @services = @services.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 3 )
 end
```

this code, my control try paginate pages 3 to 3. In views:

```html
<%= paginate @organ.services %>
```

As i want call the services with relationship
to each organ i insert que last code im my view.

The result are:

```html
 undefined method `total_pages' for #<Mongoid::Criteria:0x007f18a8b1f338>
```

if you can help, grateful for the attention!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, it was because the commontator gem was bringing in methods from will_paginate and overriding the base ActiveRecord class.

The error was in the call stack for the page_entries_info method which seems to be a common method name between both libraries.

To fix, you can explicitly reference the method with this:

So the view code:

```
<%= Kaminari::Helpers::HelperMethods.page_entries_info @events %>
<%= link_to "Next", path_to_next_page(@events) %>
<%= link_to "Prev", path_to_prev_page(@events) %>
```

and in an initializer (initializers/kaminari_config.rb)

```
module Kaminari
  module Helpers
    module HelperMethods
      extend ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper
      module_function :page_entries_info
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your controller code like the following:

```
class ServicesController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @organs = Admin::Organ.all
      @services = Service.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(3)
    end
end
```

Comment: i try you code, and i think good, but the trouble continues. undefined method `total_pages' for #<Mongoid::Criteria:

Comment: @CarlosAndré `<%= paginate @organ.services %>` From where you are getting `@organ` ?

Comment: @CarlosAndré you should use this instead in your views - `<%= paginate @services %>`

Comment: in my models have a organ e a service but have a link between theys. The object @organ are who call the service's instance.

Comment: @CarlosAndré here you are trying to paginate `@services` in your controller but you are using `<%= paginate @organ.services %>` in your views.  `@services` and `@organ.services` are different. I think that is why your are getting this problem. Can you post your entire view page where you want to use pagination ?

Comment: @organ.service it is necessary, but let's go without organ.service. The trouble continues

Answer (score 0):

try this

**Old code**

```
@services = @services.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 3 )
```

**New code**

```
@services = Service.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 3 )
```

Comment: i try you code, and i think good, but the trouble continues. undefined method `total_pages' for #<Mongoid::Criteria:

Comment: Do you have any content ? may be no content in  your database.

Comment: Have content, but heve a problem to get and return this content